# Integration of hubot with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hubot

I installed hubot and installed hubot-elasticsearch.

where i can find this external-scripts.json file?

and Hubot is not giving me any reply.

Answer (score 0):

That `external-scripts.json` should be in the root directory of your hubot source code (the dir generated by `yo hubot` as described in https://hubot.github.com/docs/).

It contains an array of all the npm packages/hubot plugins you want to load:

in your case it would just be

```
['hubot-elsasticsearch']
```